# An unhandled exception ('<System.StackOverflowException>') occurred in w3wp.exe

Tags: asp.net, exception, stack-overflow, w3wp.exe

How would I debug an exception like this for an ASP.NET web application?

**Exception:**

```
An unhandled exception ('<System.StackOverflowException>') occurred in w3wp.exe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to track down a place in your code (possibly a loop) where this may be happening.  Take a look at the Event Viewer on the web server for more details on the exception.

Comment: I just attached to the w3wp.exe process.  But rather than referencing my dll, I had to add a reference to the project which threw the exception, and it showed me the top of the stack causing the issue.  There was a method that was calling itself because a condition wasn't met.  It was supposed to be a recursive call with an eventual end.  This logic went to infinite and beyond.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Nothing like asking a question about a stack overflow...on StackOverflow.

Comment: Haha! That's what I thought too.  It was meant to be asked.